# kestrel in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

let's say you have multiple applications on a server. Is there is 1 kestrel instance handling multiple applications request or will there different kestrel instances handling different asp.net core web applications?

Can anybody provide me any links or a post where i can find out how a request travels from the client to server for ASP.NET core applications. see this SO post without an answer. [The Relationship of Kestrel server and Program.cs in ASP.NET Core request processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418459/the-relationship-of-kestrel-server-and-program-cs-in-asp-net-core-request-proces)

Comment: The diagram in that other SO post is pretty wrong. Kestrel vs IIS is an either-or ("xor") choice. You can't use both at the same time, unless your are using IIS separately, which you could use as a reverse proxy.

Comment: @omajid You can indeed host a .Net Core app that uses Kestrel using IIS. In that case, IIS acts as a reverse proxy.

Comment: I guess I was wrong. Can you point me to docs so I can learn more?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Kestrel is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core. Kestrel is the web server that's included and enabled by default in ASP.NET Core project templates. For the http request process, you could check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#kestrel):

[image]

So, from the above document, we can see that each Asp.net core application will have their own Kestrel server to host the application. And, by default when using Kestrel, ASP.NET Core binds to: `http://localhost:5000` and `https://localhost:5001`, if there have multiple applications, you should set them use different port or endpoint. Reference: [Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0).